# How to pronounce the word "рождéния"?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am struggling with the word "рождéния". I have used Google Translate but I want to run this by you. You are smarter than the Google machines.

Is the prounaciation "rozdenja" or "razdenja". I assume that with the "я" I shoukd in this case end the word with an "-ja". Let me know what you think about this. I am using that word together in a sentence with: "день рождéния".

Comment: Learn Russian transcription and probnounciation rules.

Comment: `01:03:22` *Само собою разумеется, что ротик раскрывался при этом случае очень грациозно. Ко дню __рождения__ приготовляемы были сюрпризы:…* Гоголь Николай - Мёртвые души I Том. Часть 1 (аудиокнига) https://youtu.be/-U3UUsPMqzY?t=1h3m22s

Comment: `06:03:29` *Уже родились они с ним в минуту __рождения__ его в свет, и не дано ему сил отклониться от них.* Гоголь Николай - Мёртвые души II Том. https://youtu.be/eSh3rmZUbkY?t=6h3m29s

Answer (score 1):

(Using English pronunciation shorthand)

You can pronounce it as "**rƏzh- D'EH- knee- yah**" ('k' in 'knee' is silent of course).  The third syllable is different in the word "*рожденья*", note the soft sign where in the other '*и*' is.  *That* word is pronounced as "**rƏzh- D'EN'- yah**".

As you can see, in both the letter 'я' stands by itself and hence needs to contain the fricative(?) 'j' sound (English 'y').

Comment: The schwa in the first syllable isn't standard. Except in the south, it's "razh-" with a full [a].

Comment: @NikolayErshov Full [a]? Are you from Moscow? ;) "S dnyom raaaazhdenya" :)

Comment: Not "***S*** dnom", surely!  "***Z*** dnyom..."

Comment: @codeholic Pre-emphatic а's are full, as in unreduced, in all Central Russian pronunciations. The regional differences are purely quantitative. Anyway, yes I am from Moscow and that little impression you did is how people talk in Pskov, not Moscow. Moscow [a]'s are wide and sharp, not long-drawn. *S dnyom rA!!zhdeniya* :)